# How to return SafeArray from C++ (ATL) to VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, atl

I created a ATL project and I got a function like

idl File:

```
[id(1)] HRESULT COM_TEST( [in] int parm_count, [in, out] SAFEARRAY(PARM) *parm, [out, retval] short *return_code )
```

cpp file:

```
STDMETHODIMP CTEST::COM_TEST( int parm_count, SAFEARRAY **parm, short *return_code
{
    *return_code = 0;
    for( long i = 0 ; i < parmc ; i++ )
    {
        PARM value;
        value.data = _bstr_t("This is a ACK" );  //data is BSTR type 
        SafeArrayPutElement( *parm, &i, &value );
    }

return S_OK;
}
```

Then I called it from VB. NET

vb file:

```
Dim RetCode As Short
Dim TestArray As ATL_TESTLib.ITEST
Dim parm() As ATL_TESTLib.PARM
TestArray = New ATL_TESTLib.TEST

ReDim parm(1)
parm(0).data = "This is request A"
parm(1).data = "This is request B"
RetCode = TestArray.COM_TEST( 2, parm )
```

However, I got a AccessViolationException.

My question is how do I input a array and output it?

Comment: Change the argument to SAFEARRAY* parm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I got a compiler error "overloaded member not found in CTEST".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to modify my header file. However, I still got the AccessViolationException after I changed my header file.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you provide third argument in this call?

```
RetCode = TestArray.COM_TEST( 2, parm )
```

you are using this argument in your function (*return_code = 0;), perhaps this is why it breaks?

Comment: No, [out,retval] becomes the return value after Tlbimp conversion.

Comment: well, yes and no, it is return value, but cpp needs a pointer for that value/variable (that should be created somewhere else)... cpp part doesn't create this value it assumes that it's already there (passed on via pointer), so if you send let's say (2, parm, NULL), then cpp will break trying to access NULL pointer...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I mark the line "SafeArrayPutElement( *parm, &i, &value );", it will be work. So, I don't think the problem is argument.